# FaceBook Custom Like button in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-like, fb-graph

I want to put a custom like button(not the one provided from FB) in iOS app to like the Wordpress feeds which also getting the FB Post ID. So I want to implement the functionality in my app when user taps the like button then it should be reflected to FB DataBase corresponding to that FB Post Id. What steps are required to achieve the same?

Thanks